# Defining charateristic of light wave?

Tags: optics, waves, electromagnetic-radiation

*"Light is refracted when it travels from one medium to another."* Does the sentence show that light is a wave?

Comment: Why do you think it does? It's not really clear where this question is coming from.

Answer (score 3):

Not really. You can make particle-based theories of light - generally known as Newton's corpuscular theory of light - which correctly model refraction. This is done by assuming that the velocity of light in e.g. water is faster than in air, so that the particles experience a force towards the water at the interface, making them change direction.

If you could measure the speed of light in water, then this could be ruled out with such a measurement. However, [practical Earth-bound measurements first took place around 1850](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fizeau%E2%80%93Foucault_apparatus), by which time the corpuscular theory was pretty much dead.

What killed it is [interference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interference_(wave_propagation)), and in particular [Young's double slit experiment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Young%27s_interference_experiment) in 1801 and with a final blow in 1807 with the detection of the [Poisson-Arago spot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arago_spot).

Comment: Emilio, do you agree that electric fields are quantized, that there has to be an interaction between photon (electron, other particles as well) and the surface electrons of the slits? Could you agree too, that Young could not know this? Could you agree, that the intensity distribution behind any edge(s) is the image of that quantized field betwenn the beam particles and the surface elektrons of the edge(s)?

Comment: That is pretty much chock full of misconceptions. The fields are quantized, yes, but the source that Young used was in an essentially classical state, which can be modelled perfectly using classical EM plus shot noise and thermal effects, so the quantized nature of the fields is explicitly **not** required to explain this experiment. Furthermore, the quantization of the field is overlaid on top of its wave nature: photons are quantized excitations of each classical mode, and the modes themselves exhibit the wave behaviour that causes the double-slit interference. (cont.)

Comment: There is nothing mysterious about single-photon double-slit experiments (though single-electron experiments, of course, are another matter), and the counterintuitive interferences of quantum theory are those of Hong-Ou-Mandel interferometry. I should also point out that the newtonian corpuscular theory is very different from the modern quantized theory; Young and Arago's experiments rule out the former but of course not the latter, which is the only thing I'm claiming. Finally, your concerns are waaay removed from the level of the OP's question.

Comment: Thank you for response. Please, let it work over night and try to calculate. Take in account the needed sharpness of the edges, try to use electric potential. Do it for electrons. It is time after  more than 100 years.

Comment: That is muddled and unintelligible. If you feel my claims here are incorrect then the onus is on you to prove so. Otherwise, please take your concerns to places where the OP is at an appropriate level.

Answer (score 0):

The sentence can be proved by Fermat's principle and it is not relevant to wave nature of light. Waves have some properties like velocity (and could be different in different media), phase and the important property called *interaction*.

When we say light is a wave, we must check the above properties in it. And the first experiment that showed that, light is a wave, was double-slit experiment. The experiment is meaningless without regarding *interaction*.